# Fast check files exists in other server

Tags: php, file, exists

I try check is exists in other file, if file exists server response HTTP 200 if not HTTP 302.
now i try check with get_headers() function but it to slow, because files size about 2mb-10mb and i check about 20 file in a while and it spend about 5-10 sec.
Perhaps there are other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using curl with the CURLOPT_NOBODY option.

Example:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.other-server.com/file.jpg");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$response_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

$response_code will contain the HTTP response code.

Comment: Nice now ~1 sec with 10 files.
Thanks